# Ubuntu 10.2 to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS migration with mdadm (software RAID)

Tags: mdadm, migration

I am very hesitant to push the "Upgrade" button that I see in my Software Updates program.
The reason for this is the fact that my server is configured as Backup server with software raid. 
Is there any way to make this move save? I have read a couple of questions here which did not sound very encouraging.

Is there any way to do this save ?

thanks
PF

Comment: You mean 10.04 not 10.2?

Answer (score 0):

The way you make it safe is the same way you make simply having the system in the first place safe: make backups.  Should anything go wrong ( which is rare, but can happen ), you restore the backup.

Comment: I am thinking about using a live CD for the version that I want to upgrade to. This way I will be able to see if it sees the partitions by default.The other way around this would be to add a disk to this system and make that disk bootable and primary. Right now I am using the md0 array as boot device ...

Comment: @PF4AskUbuntu, the livecd does not come with `mdadm`.